# How do I configure the git hub search api to search my profile

Tags: javascript, api

I recently started making my portfolio and would like to add something similar to looking for repositories that I have with the github API but I have no idea how to make it work.

I used this code based on the documentation:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token <my-token>'
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/<my-nickname>', headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

Comment: What permissions does that token have?

Comment: Token have "user" and "read:user" permissions.

Answer (score 0):

replace  with your username

like:- `https://api.github.com/users/VenomFate-619`

to get a list of repositories hit `https://api.github.com/users/VenomFate-619/repos`